# Google Wallet digital goods JWT postback fields

Tags: android-pay

Is there any documentation as to what other fields are included in the response of the JWT postback when a transaction is completed?

I noticed from documentation [HERE](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions) that an extra field is added for cancellations, ie **statusCode**.

Now to the point:

1. Does / can the postback JWT contain the email of the buyer?
2. Is there a field we can set when constructing the initial JWT request that will request wallet to relay the email?
3. In the old checkout, there was a mechanism of querying checkout with the orderID in order to retrieve the order details (and thus buyer email), is there an API in digital goods that does this too?

I'd like the email to relay activation codes when payment is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#jwt) is probably what you are looking for - available fields for single and subscription Jwt
- Postback Jwts:

  - [Single Item](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/postback#jwt)
  - [Subscriptions/cancelations](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions#6)

> - Does / can the postback JWT contain the email of the buyer?
> - Is there a field we can set when constructing the initial JWT request that will request wallet to relay the email?

- Does? - no
- Can? - sort of, you can use `sellerData` and "load it yourself" - perhaps obtain it from your app (first). You can also look into [Google+ sign in](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) (it's a separate API though, so you'l have to work that). The idea is that at the end of the day it's a `Google Account` (to use/have *Wallet*, *Google+* etc.)

> In the old checkout, there was a mechanism of querying checkout with the orderID in order to retrieve the order details (and thus buyer email), is there an API in digital goods that does this too?

AFAIK (I'm not a Googler) there is no current API like the one in Google Checkout - it's a wish list for me too :)

hth...

Comment: The documentation is what I actually linked to, so nothing new there, however (and this has nothing to do with you), why on earth do we have to fondle about another API to get hold of the email? And with the new feature of being able to email G+ users via G+, why is there no intergration with digital goods of that feature seeing you need to have a G+ account to use Wallet? This Checkout to Wallet Digital goods migration is more hassle than I envisaged, but kudos to you for the idea.

Comment: @Nepaluz Well, it works if you wanted it to be "all Google". In a flow where you have your own "user accounts", _payment flow_ would be separated from "user mgmt"

Comment: that is as convoluted a response that I have read in a while, but ok!